# “Something wrong--perhaps a missing \item”

Tags: enumerate, algorithmic

By trying to compile the code below the following error will be raised for each \item entry.

Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item

```
\begin{algorithmic}
       \begin{enumerate}
      \item  Soit $S$ un corpus en langue source et $T$ un corpus en langue cible.
      \item Calculer l'ensemble des triggers inter-langues 2 $\rightarrow$ 1 tel que la séquence gauche
    des triggers appartient au corpus $S$ et la séquence droite appartient au corpus $T$.
    \\Pour chaque séquence source on garde seulement les meilleurs triggers.
     \item Trier les séquences (partie gauche des triggers) par ordre décroissant des la valeur
    de l'IMC.
      \item Segmenter le corpus source en fonction des séquence extraites.
        \item Exécuter 2, 3 et 4 en inversant les corpus source et cible.
        \item Réitérer ces différentes étape précédentes jusqu'à atteindre la taille maximale fixée d'avance.
        \item Calculer l'ensemble des triggers inter-langues 1 $\rightarrow$ 1 tel que la séquence gauche
    appartient au corpus source et la séquence droite au corpus cible.
       \end{enumerate}
    %En itérant ces différentes étapes, nous obtenons à une listes de séquences de taille variable.
         \label{alg} 
        \end{algorithmic}
     \end{algorithm}
```

Any idea please?

thank you

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4):

`algorithmic` environment is a special environment that uses the package commands for typesetting psuedo-code, here you just want the `algorithm` float containing an enumerate

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm,algorithmic}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
       \begin{enumerate}
      \item  Soit $S$ un corpus en langue source et $T$ un corpus en langue cible.
      \item Calculer l'ensemble des triggers inter-langues 2 $\rightarrow$ 1 tel que la séquence gauche
    des triggers appartient au corpus $S$ et la séquence droite appartient au corpus $T$.
    \\Pour chaque séquence source on garde seulement les meilleurs triggers.
     \item Trier les séquences (partie gauche des triggers) par ordre décroissant des la valeur
    de l'IMC.
      \item Segmenter le corpus source en fonction des séquence extraites.
        \item Exécuter 2, 3 et 4 en inversant les corpus source et cible.
        \item Réitérer ces différentes étape précédentes jusqu'à atteindre la taille maximale fixée d'avance.
        \item Calculer l'ensemble des triggers inter-langues 1 $\rightarrow$ 1 tel que la séquence gauche
    appartient au corpus source et la séquence droite au corpus cible.
       \end{enumerate}
    %En itérant ces différentes étapes, nous obtenons à une listes de séquences de taille variable.
         \label{alg} 
     \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What's a soecial environment?

Comment: @Au101 sorry my poor typing, fixed!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oh! Thanks! I'm sorry, I didn't mean to draw attention to a simple mistake, but I originally assumed it was either something entirely new on me, or it was a typo for 'social environment', and I'm thinking, what's a social environment, one that goes drinking with its friends at the weekends? Wearing braces of course ;)