# Package `algorithmicx` erorr : `Something wrong perhaps a missing \item`

Tags: standalone, algorithmicx

Following is my MWE

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85} % needed of lualatex
\documentclass[]{standalone}
% \usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}
% \begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Procedure{SequenceResponse}{$S_n$}\Comment{Hellow}
        \State $a \gets b$
    \EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
% \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Even on this simple example, it fails:

```
Document Style algorithmicx 1.2 - a greatly improved `algorithmic' style
)
Document Style - pseudocode environments for use with the `algorithmicx' style
) (./algorithm.aux)

! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.8     \Procedure
                {SequenceResponse}{$S_n$}\Comment{Hellow}
?
```

I guess it is related to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332789/something-wrong-perhaps-a-missing-item). I tried wrapping it between `algorithm` environment but no success. Probably `standalone` is doing something.

I am using Texlive-2017. I updated it today (Aug 07, 2017) using `tlmgr`.

Comment: Wrapping it between `\begin{figure} \end{figure}` seems to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the varwidth option:

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85} % needed of lualatex
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
% \usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}
% \begin{algorithm}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Procedure{SequenceResponse}{$S_n$}\Comment{Hellow}
        \State $a \gets b$
    \EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
% \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```